# Failed to read file data using javascript in splunk

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, splunk

i was trying to write a javascript program which read list of token from the configuration file and set the token. But javascript program failed to read my local configuration file.

javascript program below

```
 require([
    "splunkjs/mvc",
    "splunkjs/mvc/simplexml/ready!"
    ],
        function(mvc) {
        var defaultTokenModel = splunkjs.mvc.Components.getInstance("default");
        alert("start");
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.status == 200) {
                var allText = xhttp.responseText;
                alert('Text = ' + allText)
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "rejected_panels.conf", true);
        xhttp.send();
        alert("end");

        defaultTokenModel.set('home_panel_1', 'yes');
});
```

I am accessing javascript from splunk's simple xml as below

```
 <form script="rejected_panels.js">
    ....
    ....
 </form>
```

I got this error in chrome browser

```
rejected_panels.js:21 GET http://localhost:8000/en-GB/app/multi_tOP/rejected_panels.conf 404
```

Kindly Help me on this.

Comment: [`404`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) indicates file `Not Found` . Have you tried using full path to file at `.open()`?

Comment: @guest271314 i got "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." error when i give full path